# What is the name of the theorem that if $\int _0^\infty f(x)$ converges then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, soft-question, summation

I haven't had a formal introduction to series and summation, but I have read somewhere that to find out if a sum converges/diverges, you can take the integral and if the integral has a limit when evaluated from 1 to $\infty$ then, a limit exists; if a limit does not exist, the series diverges.

Can anybody tell me the name of this theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). Not a super fancy name.

Comment: Another name (especially used in Russian language literature): The Maclaurin–Cauchy test.

Comment: @njguliyev : are you sure you it is not Maclaurin–Cauchy Integral test? without the word integral in that test it is easy to mistake for Cauchy condensation test.